# How to make animation

Tags: python, jupyterbook

I want to show life-game simulation. However this code doesn't show animation but image.
Please tell me the solution.
I tried "%matplotlib notebook" or "%matplotlib nbagg".
The below is my code.

```
%matplotlib notebook
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

def f(N,cell):
    cell_new=cell.copy()
    for i in range(1,cell.shape[0]-1):
        for j in range(1,cell.shape[1]-1):
            if cell[i,j]==1:
                N_shu=cell[i-1:i+2,j-1:j+2].sum()-1
                if N_shu==2 or N_shu==3:
                    cell_new[i,j]=1
                else:
                    cell_new[i,j]=0
            else:
                N_shu=cell[i-1:i+2,j-1:j+2].sum()
                if N_shu==3:
                    cell_new[i,j]=1
                else:
                    cell_new[i,j]=0
    return cell_new

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
plt.tick_params(labelbottom=False,labelleft=False,labelright=False,labeltop=False)
ims=[]
N=10
cell=np.zeros((N+2,N+2),dtype=np.int32)
mat=np.random.randint(0,2,size=(N,N),dtype=np.int32)
cell[1:-1,1:-1]=mat

for _ in range(100):
    cell=f(N,cell)
    im=plt.imshow(cell,cmap=plt.cm.gray_r,animated=True)
    ims.append([im])
    
ani=animation.ArtistAnimation(fig,ims,interval=100)
plt.show()
```